# How to use unmanaged DLLs in SharePoint project?

Tags: 2013, error, deployment, codeplex

I am using [SPSS .NET interop library](http://spss.codeplex.com/)
to export data to SAV file.

I get error

> System.TypeInitializationException was caught
>     HResult=-2146233036
>     Message=The type initializer for 'Spss.SpssThinWrapper' threw an exception.
>     Source=Spss
>     TypeName=Spss.SpssThinWrapper
>
> InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
>          HResult=-2146233052
>          Message=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\bin\win64\spssio64.dll not found.

Sharepoin can't found external dll although it exists in that location.

How can I use this kind of libraries with SharePoint projects?

Any advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that you have deployed those libraries to all servers?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I don't know why spss.dll cannot found dependant dlls.

Comment: Check the permissions on the folder tree to the dll. First I would try with Everyone Full Control to the entire path, then strengthen the security step by step if it works. Are you sure this dll has no other external dependencies? I would also enable the Fusion log to see if their are some other problems with the managed dlls (see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Comment: @pholpar, your answer helped me. I changed permissions to bin folder. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad, that it helped. Then I post it as answer, so you can accept it as a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions on the folder tree to the dll. First I would try with Everyone Full Control to the entire path, then strengthen the security step by step if it works.